# node js fs-extra outputFile data parameter as variable?

Tags: node.js, fs-extra

I delcare a function to create a file with path, and data as variable. here my code

```
const fse = require("fs-extra");
function createFile(name, contents) {
    fse.outputFile(name, contents, function(err) {

        }
    };
```

than

```
var name = "./path/file1";
var contents = "file1content";
createFile(name, contents);

name = "./path/file2";
contents = "file2content";
createFile(name, contents);

name = "./path/file3";
contents = "file3content";
createFile(name, contents);
```

file1, file2, file3 is created, but files's contents all are `undefined`
is there any way to make my code possible?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your function `createFile` has arguments as `(name, contents)` but why are you using different parameter names here `fse.outputFile(fullPathFileName, first_contents`.

Match them as below and try,

```
const fse = require("fs-extra");
function createFile(fullPathFileName, first_contents) {
    fse.outputFile(fullPathFileName, first_contents, function(err) {

    });
```

then,

```
var name = "./path/file1";
var contents = "file1content";
createFile(name, contents);

name = "./path/file2";
contents = "file2content";
createFile(name, contents);

name = "./path/file3";
contents = "file3content";
createFile(name, contents);
```

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, I edited my own code before post here but not edit complete. Sorry for that. Re-editd my post. Thanks

Comment: Your function has the variables name same as the calling code. If they are in one file then they will create an issue. Try with different variables name as in my sample above